# Should react class methods be pure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering should I use 'this.props' and 'this.state' inside React class methods or prepare only needed data from state and props outside and pass it to a method as parameters?

First option looks quicker, but **maybe** more error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd treat the component methods quite the same as usual methods in javascript. For me it means that just by looking at the method header I can at least suppose, base on the name and entry params, what the specific method is responsible for.

Second thing is, that it can depend on component shape itself.

Lets imagine that in your component you got the method named 'markPersonAsAbsent'.

If your component just handle single person than in fact can be quite obvious that we should operate on something like this.props.person.

But if your component is more like a list of people which can be inline edited, not just the info card of a single person, than for sure we'd expect to pass a specific person as param to that method.

In that scenario of course we can argue that the components are wrongly designed and should be more atomized, but just wanted to describe simple example.

So personally I just try to focus how to make my components readable and let's say 'predictable'.

Answer (score 0):

It is not error prone, since this.state and this.props are read only properties, so you can't change their values directly.